# Linking from a .html file to an external stylesheet?

Tags: css, html

I've seen the following issue discussed on this site, but none of the suggested fixes worked for me. I'll paste in the text of all of the files and my directory structure. It's nothing more than linking from an .html file to an external stylesheet. The result should be - that when lounge.html runs, lounge.css should be applied as a style sheet so that the styles specified are shown in elixer.html and directions.html. But these styles do not show up.

I've seen suggestions that indicate this can't be run locally on a computer, but can be run on a web server, but I can't imagine that's the case. Any ideas? Thanks in advance. Here's the directory structure:

```
C:/HFHTMLCSS/chapter2/lounge/lounge.css

C:/HFHTMLCSS/chapter2/lounge/lounge.html

C:/HFHTMLCSS/chapter2/lounge/elixer.html

C:/HFHTMLCSS/chapter2/lounge/directions.html


When I run lounge.html, 

lounge.css:

h1, h2  {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: gray;
}

h1  {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

p  {
    color: maroon;
}

lounge.html:

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Head First Lounge</title>

        <link type="text.css" rel = "stylesheet" href="lounge.css">
  </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Welcome to the Head First Lounge</h1>
    <p>
    <img src="C:/HFHTMLCSS/chapter2/lounge/images/drinks.gif" alt="Drinks">
</p>
<p>    
       Join us any evening for refreshing <a href="C:/HFHTMLCSS/chapter2/lounge/elixir.html">elixers</a>
       conversation and maybe a game or two of 
       <em>Dance Dance Revolution</em>.
       Wireless access is always provided;  
       BYOWS (Bring your own web server).
    </p>
    <h2>Directions</h2>
    <p>
      You'll find us right in the center of downtown Webville.   
      If you need help finding us, check out our <a href="C:/HFHTMLCSS/chapter2/lounge/directions.html">detailed directions</a>.
      Come join us!
    </p>
  </body>
</html>

elixer.html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Head First Lounge Elixirs</title>
    <link type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet"  href=lounge.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Our Elixirs</h1>

    <h2>Green Tea Cooler</h2>
    <p>
      <img src="images/green.jpg">
      Chock full of vitamins and minerals, this elixir
      combines the healthful benefits of green tea with
      a twist of chamomile blossoms and ginger root.
    </p>
    <h2>Raspberry Ice Concentration</h2>
    <p>
      <img src="images/lightblue.jpg">
      Combining raspberry juice with lemon grass,
      citrus peel and rosehips, this icy drink
      will make your mind feel clear and crisp.
    </p>
    <h2>Blueberry Bliss Elixir</h2>
    <p>
      <img src="images/blue.jpg">
      Blueberries and cherry essence mixed into a base
      of elderflower herb tea will put you in a relaxed
      state of bliss in no time.
    </p>
    <h2>Cranberry Antioxidant Blast</h2>
    <p>
      <img src="images/red.jpg">
      Wake up to the flavors of cranberry and hibiscus
      in this vitamin C rich elixir.
    </p>
    <p>
        <a href="beverages/lounge.html">Back to the Lounge</a>
    </p>

  </body>
</html>

directions.html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Head First Lounge Directions</title>
    <link type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet" href="lounge.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Directions</h1>
    <p>Take the 305 S exit to Webville - go 0.4 mi</p>
    <p>Continue on 305 - go 12 mi</p>
    <p>Turn right at Structure Ave N - go 0.6 mi</p>
    <p>Turn right and head toward Structure Ave N - go 0.0 mi</p>
    <p>Turn right at Structure Ave N - go 0.7 mi</p>
    <p>Continue on Structure Ave S - go 0.2 mi</p>
    <p>Turn right at SW Presentation Way - go 0.0 mi</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not something you run. It's a document format, roughly comparable to a word processor's, that your web browser can render to a layout. The syntax of HTML requires using a URI (a *Universal Resource Identifier*) for the `src` attribute of various elements like images or style sheets, and it's important to quote attributes correctly. `elixer.html` is simply missing a double quote before the CSS file name.

By the way, those links and images are bound to break on a real web server as well. What you put in there is half-Unix, half-Windows syntax with unixish forward slashes and Windows' drive letter. That won't work. Just make them relative URIs like

```
<img src="images/drinks.gif" alt="Drinks">
<a href="elixir.html">
```

That way they'll work on your local box just as well as on a web server.